# Distribution line excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I require a formula which will redistribute previous months values dependant on the current month. (this will always be staggered by 2 months I.e. if the current month is June it will redistribute May and Aprils percentages to the remaining months based on a percentage already calculated.

Please see picture below which will aid my explanation of what is required.

[image]

Taking June for example the 2% and 3% for April and May would be re-distributed to ensure the summary column always = 100% however distribution would be calculated based on the % of the distribution line.

The formula I am currently using is;

=IF=(($E$19+$F$19)*G19)+G19

However I assume this needs to be nested into IFS statements to ensure the formula is always staggered by two months and does not take into account any previous months however I am not sure how to do this

Comment: which cell is E19?

Comment: 2% within the April column

Comment: The table you showed is how you want the results to be? Just wondering because you said you wanted the summary column to be always 100%. If you want them all to be 100%, you would have to change the distribution percentages for each starting month ("cap.rev of month" divided by "sum of caprev of starting month to last month(march)"). Example L22: starting month would be July

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for however was unsure how to do this; could you demonstrate in a formula term what you mean. Slightly confused by your terminology used?

Comment: I posted it as an answer, please let me know if the results are what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

This goes into cell G21, and can then be copied into H21:P15 via pasteSpecial>Formulas:

`=G$15/sum($G$15:$P$15)`

In row 22, you would have:

`=H$15/sum($H$15:$P$15)`

You would have to modify the formula in this way for each row.